# Dynamic R objects using apply functions

Tags: r, function, apply

I've got a long R code now and I'm trying to make it more readable.

Below is a small chunk from my code -

```
U2OverlayG1 <- GrowthorDiff(U2Overlay, Metadata, 1)
U1OverlayG1 <- GrowthorDiff(U1Overlay, Metadata, 1)
BLOverlayG1 <- GrowthorDiff(BLOverlay, Metadata, 1)
D1OverlayG1 <- GrowthorDiff(D1Overlay, Metadata, 1)
D2OverlayG1 <- GrowthorDiff(D2Overlay, Metadata, 1)

U2G1 <- GrowthorDiff(U2, Metadata, 1)
U1G1 <- GrowthorDiff(U1, Metadata, 1)
BLG1 <- GrowthorDiff(BL, Metadata, 1)
D1G1 <- GrowthorDiff(D1, Metadata, 1)
D2G1 <- GrowthorDiff(D2, Metadata, 1)
```

As you'd observe, there is a lot of repetition and I'm wondering if this could be automated using apply functions or a better way (if there exists one). When I try creating dynamic objects using the paste/paste0 function, it returns a string rather than an object. Similarly, I want dynamic objects in both LHS and RHS, i.e., D2G1 and D2 (parameter of function GrowthorDiff) should be dynamic. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please share some data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Don't do it with separate variables.  Put them all into a list.  Then use `lapply()` on the list.